# Why is math being saved to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with a column populated by a formula:

```
    if ($row['importfee'] > 0) {
$sum_total= $row['stock']*($row['cost']*($row['importfee']/100)+$row['cost']+$row['prepcost']);
print ($sum_total); 
$total_price += $sum_total;
    }else{
$sum_total= $row['stock']*($row['cost']+$row['prepcost']);
echo $sum_total; 
$total_price += $sum_total;
    }
```

ex. stock is 400, cost is 200, prepcost is 0 - output is 80000 
This column is displayed as plain text, not an input.

Next I send $sum_total to a hidden input for $_POSTing:

```
<input name='totalcost[]' type='text' id='totalcost' value='<?php echo $sum_total ?>'>
```

ex. output is 80000

Finally I update my database:

```
$totalcost= $_POST['totalcost'];

$sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET
productname='".$productname[$i]."',stock='".$stock[$i]."',cost='".$cost[$i]."',maker='".$maker[$i]."',customer='".$customer[$i]."',department='".$department[$i]."',comment='".$comment[$i]."',reportdate='".$reportdate."',page='".$page[$i]."',importfee='".$importfee[$i]."',prepcost='".$prepcost[$i]."',totalcost='".$totalcost[$i]."*(".$cost[$i]."+".$prepcost[$i].");'
WHERE id='".$id2[$i]."'";
```

And I get a wonderful surprise in my database:
ex. database entry [totalcost] 80000*(200+);

I expected the entry to be [totalcost] 80000.

Why is the formula being sent to the database but not echoed in my table? How can I send just the value 80000 without the math to the database? I'm working on a WAMP server at the moment if t makes any difference.

Comment: echo $sql, and you will see why

Comment: Please don't make queries like that. It's a gaping security hole. Dunno what database-handler you're using, but look up "prepared queries", please, and do use either mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: And, your code is working exactly as it should - here's what you put into the `[totalcost]` column: `totalcost='".$totalcost[$i]."*(".$cost[$i]."+".$prepcost[$i].");'`All of that goes into the column.

Comment: The reason is that you have quotes around the formula, so it's a literal string, not math.

Comment: But I don't understand how that could be showing up in the database. Is the `totalcost` column really `VARCHAR` rather than `NUMERIC`?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I feel foolish sitting here thinking and searching for the problem the past hour but it is right in front of me. Thank you for pointing it out, it was left over code from when I started.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the tip, still new to coding. Also yes its a VARCHAR, until testing is finished and limits decided most columns are VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added as answer (from comment):

Your code is working exactly as it should - here's what you put into the `[totalcost]` column:

```
totalcost='".$totalcost[$i]."*(".$cost[$i]."+".$prepcost[$i]‌​.");
```

All of that goes into the column.